# python xlrd string match

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I couldnt find anything in the API. Is there a way to return the row number or coordinate of a cell based on a string match? For instance: You give the script a string and it scans through the .xls file and when it finds a cell with the matching string, it returns the coordinate or row number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
     row = sheet.row_values(i)
     for j in range(len(row)):
          if row[j] == search_value:
                return i,j
return None
```

something like that... just a basic search

Comment: Im getting this error `File "mp3.py", line 22    return i,j SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: well its not meant to be a direct copy and paste you need to put it in a function and set the sheet value by extracting the correct sheet from the workbook i think its like woorkbook.getsheetbyindex(0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following function, thank you Joran

```
def look4_xlrd (search_value, sheet) :
lines = []
columns = []
for i in range (sheet.nrows) :
    row = sheet.row_values(i)
    for j in range(len(row)) :
        if row[j] == search_value :
            lines.append(i)
            columns.append(j)
    del row
return lines, columns
```